# Facebook php sdk: getSessionFromRedirect returns null

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, phalcon

I am using Phalcon. The following function is called when accessing route: /registration/facebook/access:

```
public function facebookAccess()
{
    $app = new FacebookApp($this->config);
    $app->initialize();

    $loginUrl = $app->getRegistrationLink($this->fbRedirectUrl);

    $this->view->setVar('loginUrl', $loginUrl);
}
```

$app->initialize() calls session_start() and FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication with my app id and secret. The link appears correctly. When I click on the link, I get redirected to /registration/facebook/process:

```
public function facebookProcess()
{
    $app = new FacebookApp($this->config);
    $app->initialize();

    if (!$app->startSession($this->fbRedirectUrl))
    {
        if ($app->getSessionError())
            $this->dispatchError($app->getSessionError());
        else
            $this->dispatchErrorStub('FACEBOOK_SESSION_INVALID');

        return;
    }

    $fbData = $app->getUser();

    if (!$fbData->save())
    {
        $this->dispatchErrorOn($fbData);
        return;
    }

    $this->view->setVar('fbData', $fbData);
}
```

where startSession is defined as follows:

```
public function startSession($redirectUrl)
{
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirectUrl);

    try 
    {
        $this->session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
        $this->sessionError = false;

        if (!$this->session)
            return false;

        return true;
    } 
    catch(Exception $ex) 
    {
        $this->session = false;
        $this->sessionError = $ex->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the returned session is always true. The code worked fine yesterday, I just did some refactoring. Cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: Is `startSession` method defined in your controller?

Comment: No, it is in utility class. Nonetheless I also tried using the code directly in the controller, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It resolved itself without doing nothing... still I don't know what went wrong.